# How to create an image dataset from a video for deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, dataset, image-classification

I am working on a research project with primary data.For this reason,I captured some video then now I want to make a dataset for this image classification project.How to do this step by step?

I rendered images from the video with 60fps.

Comment: I would split the videos, then use ffmpeg to extract the pictures from each sample, and group them by folder (one for each category)

After that, you can train the model based on the folders